# Can I do a text search against a pattern when using Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdoql

All examples I'm seeing show how to pull up entities matching a string exactly.

Is there an equivalent to a LIKE query?

Also, if it helps, I'm thinking of using the result for an auto-completing a text box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google App Engine: Is it possible to do a Gql LIKE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786/google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-do-a-gql-like-query)

There is a startsWith keyword in gql:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/972599e12c8e7fc8/83c9d1f1b78898ab?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=StartsWith#83c9d1f1b78898ab