# GQL query with "like" operator

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google App Engine: Is it possible to do a Gql LIKE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786/google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-do-a-gql-like-query)

In SQL (T-SQL at least) you can write a query that uses the "like" operator, something like this:

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn like '%something%'
```

Is there any way to do this in GQL?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786/google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-do-a-gql-like-query