# how to get the info which contains 'sss', not "= ",

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filter

this is my code:

```
class Marker_latlng(db.Model):
    geo_pt = db.GeoPtProperty()

class Marker_info(db.Model):
    info = db.StringProperty()
    marker_latlng =db.ReferenceProperty(Marker_latlng)

q = Marker_info.all()
q.filter("info =", "sss")
```

but how to get the info which contains 'sss', not "=",

has a method like "contains "?

```
    q = Marker_info.all()
    q.filter("info contains", "sss")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172292/gql-find-all-entities-that-contain-a-substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `StringProperty`, you could use a `StringListProperty`. Before saving the info string, split it into a list of strings, containing each word.

Then, when you use `q.filter("info =", "sss")` it will match any item which contains a word which is each to `"sss"`.

For something more general, you could look into app engine full text search.

Comment: Note that in any case you'll be limited to keyword searches or keyword prefix searches; there's no good way to do true substring searching.