# Autocomplete Textbox Example in python + Google app engine

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, autocomplete

For my google app engine application, I need to include a autocompleter Textbox which will show the name starting with the textbox value.And the name will retrieve from the google app engine datastore.

Any good tutorial or sample code please.

**Update: Please Answer for this**

I created a sample HTML code : [dl.dropbox.com/u/7384181/autocomplete/autocomplete.html](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7384181/autocomplete/autocomplete.html) .
In this html page i have creating the textbox dinamically.So currently i assign the autocomplete in the first textbox(txtProduct1) only. How do i assign the autocomplete in rest all the textbox which is going to create dynamically ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Form Auto Complete in Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243570/create-form-auto-complete-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a look at the jquery auto complete [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

**HTML :**

```
$("#search_users").autocomplete(/search/search_manager);
```

**python-controller**:

jquery autocomplete plugin by default uses variable q

```
class search_user(webapp.RequestHandler):
            q = (self.request.GET['q']).lower() 
            results=models.user.all().fetch(100) 
            for records in result:
                print records+"|"+records+"\n"

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
                                      (r'/user_auth/search_manager',search_user)]

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

simple:
```

Apply the autocomplete to a class 
$

```
(".search_users").autocomplete(/search/search_manager);
```

Comment: You're not using `q` in the datastore query!

Comment: Hi @Abdulkader, I am unable to see the original code by the OP. I have asked a similar question and I wonder if you could take a look. I would appreciate it so much: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979567/jquery-autocomplete-with-remote-json-source-google-app-engine-python

Answer (score 2):

Look into JQuery's [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin, you can use a django template tag to populate the data.  Below is an example if your data is separated by commas.

**Python:**

```
names=[name for name in db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM names")]
values={'names':','.join(names)}
self.response.out.write(template.render('template.html',values))
```

**template.html:**

```
var data = "{{names}}".split(",");
$("#example").autocomplete(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using autocomplete with GAE Python and YUI3 AutoComplete Plugin](http://novyden.blogspot.com/2011/10/autocomplete-using-google-app-engine.html).

Comment: If you identify a duplicate, you should flag it as such - not post your answer to both of them.

Comment: @NickJohnson - thanks for your suggestion that I'll follow when appropriate. But I didn't identify duplicates - you did. I happened to answer two related questions with the reference to the same blog that addresses both questions and some more.

Comment: Because both questions are _identical_, which you must have noticed when you answered both.