# How can I make my App Engine Datastore user search faster?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, python-2.7, python-memcached

I need to be able to search my users faster. A search without memcache takes 8 seconds. Now my code utilizes memcache with the help of [Not Dot Net](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching) which reduces the search time to 4 sec. My question now is, how can I make it faster?

```
qUserSearch = Utilities.deserialize_entities(memcache.get("qUserSearch"))
if not qUserSearch:
    qUserSearch = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY created DESC").fetch(100000)
    memcache.add("qUserSearch", Utilities.serialize_entities(qUserSearch))

searchLength = len(searchData) 
hits = []
gotHits = False

for u in qUserSearch:
    searchEmail = u.email[0:searchLength]
    if searchEmail == searchData:
        hits.append( u.key() )
    else:
        # Since I only search for the first x chars
        # will there never be hits after it's had hits
        if gotHits:
            break 
return hits
```

My first ideas:

- convert to ndb and SELECT only, needed, data FROM User
- SQL way, create a table with less data. Just usernames and key to metadata
- The new full text search
- The old searchable models by 3rd party devs
- Memcache only needed properties and traverese that instead of everything

Or do you have other ideas? Which once do you think I will save the most time on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also simulate the prefix search you are trying to accomplish with two inequality filters

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE email >= :1 AND email <= :2", searchData, unicode(searchData) + u"\ufffd")
```

Note: This answer was taken from the second answer provided for the question [Google App Engine: Is it possible to do a Gql LIKE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786/google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-do-a-gql-like-query).

Comment: 23 ms is much better than 4325 ms. Thanks! And thanks for the source