# Google app engine IN filter

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using python 2.7, jinja2 and google app engine.

I have a database where one of the entities are string in this form:

```
"test1,test2,test3,test4,test5"
```

I try to figure a query where I will retrieve all the entities where test1 for example are in the string.

I tried the following where tags is the string property:

```
category = "test1"
mymodel.gql("WHERE tags in :1", category)
```

I have this error : `BadArgumentError: List expected for "IN" filter`

I can imagine that this is logical, since my property is string and not list, but how can I change the query to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to modify you property to be a StringListProperty rather than string for this to work.

There are not a lot of other choices either.  Use FullText Search is or something like WHoosh https://github.com/tallstreet/Whoosh-AppEngine  which also does full text search are your other alternatives.

I would personally change it to a StringListProperty.

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, the GQL is expecting a list.  Try making `category` a list:

```
category = ["test1"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. I don't have an error any more, but the query is empty.

Comment: That's because GQL doesn't perform Full Text searches, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786/google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-do-a-gql-like-query