# String contains operation on Cloud Datastore column

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I implement a contains method in Google Datastore.
Google doesn't provide a string contains filter of a property because it will cause a table scan.

How can I implement it another way.

Comment: Have you tried something? Basically this is not possible with datastore, but depending on your use case you could still implement something. Like.. index n-grams for each phrase you want to be indexes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine: Is it possible to do a Gql LIKE query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786/google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-do-a-gql-like-query)

Answer (score 2):

You are right: the Datastore, by its NoSQL nature, [does not directly support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#intro) substring matches, case-insensitive matches, or so-called full-text search. Your program would be able to implement case-insensitive matches and even full-text search using [computed properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed). This solution may work well, depending on the actual needs of the application. 
You can use the app engine search API for full-text matching on string fields. If you need to retrieve very large result sets, Datastore API is more appropriate.