# Has Google Datastore Cloud queries LIKE keyword?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I´m Looking for search values into my Datastore but I need information filtered by value. I know Datastore is no relational DB, but how could I get the goal?

I´m trying this:

```
$ds = new DatastoreClient(['keyFilePath' => 'foo.json');
$q = $ds->gqlQuery('SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE NAME LIKE "%$'.val.'%"');
$res = $ds->runQuery($q);
```

The LIKE keyword is not supported, What I can use instead?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47811/1064767

Comment: @Sammitch Could you post both links (with a short explanation) as an answer, please?
[DanCornilescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4495081/dan-cornilescu) We are talking about different products here... I wouldn't mark this as a duplicate even if the information in the other post is useful.

Comment: @RubénC. Fair enough, I retracted the vote.

Answer (score 0):

As [Sammitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064767/sammitch) suggested, you can perform Datastore queries following the instructions described [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#operators_and_comparisons) or in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786/google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-do-a-gql-like-query/47811#47811). The syntax is different, but the `regular expression` idea is the same.